# Load balance WebSocket connections to Tornado app using HAProxy?

Tags: proxy, nginx, websocket, tornado, haproxy

I am working on a Tornado app that uses websocket handlers. I'm running multiple instances of the app using Supervisord, but I have trouble load balancing websocket connections.

I know nginx does not support dealing with websockets out of the box, but I followed the instructions here http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets to use the nginx tcp_proxy module to reverse proxy websocket connections. However, this did not work since the module can't route websocket urls (ex: ws://localhost:80/something). So it would not work with the URL routes I have defined in my Tornado app.

From my research around the web, it seems that HAProxy is the way to go to load balance my websocket connections. However, I'm having trouble finding any decent guidance to setup HAProxy to load balance websocket connections and also be able to handle websocket URL routes.

I would really appreciate some detailed directions on how to get this going. I am also fully open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's not difficult to implement WebSocket in haproxy, though I admit it's not yet easy to find doc on this (hopefully this response will make one example). If you're using haproxy 1.4 (which I suppose you are) then it works just like any other HTTP request without having to do anything, as the HTTP Upgrade is recognized by haproxy.

If you want to direct the WebSocket traffic to a different farm than the rest of HTTP, then you should use content switching rules, in short :

```
 frontend pub-srv
    bind :80
    use_backend websocket if { hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket }
    default_backend http

 backend websocket
    timeout server 600s
    server node1 1.1.1.1:8080 check
    server node2 2.2.2.2:8080 check

 backend http
    timeout server 30s
    server www1 1.1.1.1:80 check
    server www2 2.2.2.2:80 check
```

If you're using 1.5-dev, you can even specify "timeout tunnel" to have a larger timeout for WS connections than for normal HTTP connections, which saves you from using overly long timeouts on the client side.

You can also combine Upgrade: WebSocket + a specific URL :

```
 frontend pub-srv
    bind :80
    acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
    acl is_ws_url path /something1 /something2 /something3
    use_backend websocket if is_websocket is_ws_url
    default_backend http
```

Last, please don't use the stupid 24h idle timeouts we sometimes see, it makes absolutely no
sense to wait for a client for 24h with an established session right now. The web is much more
mobile than in the 80s and connection are very ephemeral. You'd end up with many FIN_WAIT sockets
for nothing. 10 minutes is already quite long for the current internet.

Hoping this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative response. I will try it out today and report back. I know you expressed your dislike of high idle timeouts, and your view makes sense for most applications. I'm actually using websockets to create communication between an embedded device and a server. This device will actually always be on forever (theoretically). So is there a way to have no timeout at all?

Comment: @AmirR. am also looking to implement a similar setup, would love to hear your result for adopting the answer above.

Comment: You can disable timeouts if you want (and will get a warning). But this is always a design error because you assume the device will never fail/crash/reboot/get disconnected, which is 100% wrong. Keep in mind that timeouts are there to protect a component from another component's unexpected failure. You don't want to restart your haproxy to get rid of fantom connections when your device fails, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets does not traverse Proxies too well since **after** the handshake they are not following the normal HTTP behavior.

Try use the WebSocket (wss://) protocol (secured WS). this will use the Proxy CONNECT API which will hide the WebSocket protocol.

Comment: So you're saying if I use WSS:// then url handling can be achieved?

Comment: I disagree, quite the opposite in fact, the handshake is 100% HTTP compliant and was designed for this, but it uses the Upgrade feature of HTTP that many proxies did not care to implement in the past. If your proxy does not support the Upgrade mechanism, file a bug report to your vendor, that's important to get the web fixed !

Comment: Yes Amir, WSS bypasses the logic the proxy needs to implement from the upgrade. It causes it to handle the connection back-to-back without any intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://launchpad.net/txloadbalancer to do loadbalancing with Tornado websocket handlers. It's simple and worked well (I think).

Answer (score 0):

## http nginx (only nginx v1.3+)

```
upstream chatservice {
    #multi thread by tornado
    server 127.0.0.1:6661;
    server 127.0.0.1:6662;
    server 127.0.0.1:6663;
    server 127.0.0.1:6664;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
```

## virtual host

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name chat.domain.com;
    root /home/duchat/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
    }
    location @backend {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://chatservice;
            internal;
}
```